# jQuery Load() not loading within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to use jQuery to open an href inside a div, rather than simply linking to the new page.  I have viewed a number of tutorials but the load() function does not seem to be working for me.

Please take a look at my code and let me know what piece of puzzle is missing.

Here is my HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Jquery</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- nav links to open in div#content area -->
<a class="menu_top" href="pages/home.php">Home</a> | <a class="menu_top" href="pages/about.php">About</a> | <a class="menu_top" href="pages/contact.php">Contact</a>

<!-- div for links to open in -->
<div id="content-area"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav.js"></script>
</body>
```

And my jQuery Javascript:

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {
var href=$(this).attr('href');
alert (href);
$('#content_area').load(href);
//return false;
 });
```

I added alert to make sure the URL was being retrieved, and it is, then it would completely load then new page. So I added "return false" and it did nothing after the alert suggesting that the load() was not working.

Initially was running this through WAMP so I tried running the page directly from the folder and the browser tried to download the linked pages instead of opening them. I also tried uploading to a remote web site and got the same result as on WAMP.

Comment: You use "content_area" in the JavaScript, but "content-area" in the HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('.menu_top').click(function() {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    alert (href);
    $('#content-area').load(href);
    //return false;
});
```

Because your div is called `#content-area`, not `#content_area`.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your help. As I was trying your suggestions, I grasped at a few more straws myself and found that when I uncommented the "return false" it worked.